# Changing background textfield in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have read a few questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081573/change-border-color-of-text-field-in-extjs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214297/how-do-i-change-color-of-a-textfield-using-extjs) on this on StackOverflow but nothing seems to help with my situation.

I want to set the **background color** and **border** of a textfield dynamically.

My textfield looks like this, but the background is still not changed :

[image]

This is because of an image in the background that gives a shading effect. So I try and remove it in the CSS using *background-image:none;* and *background:none;* :

```
.invalid-component {
    background-color : #f4f777;
    border: 2px dotted #ffee27; //works!!
    background-image:none;
    background:none;
}
```

This still has no effect, the image is not removed and the background color does not change. Any help?

Comment: Hi Oliver, I can help you with that but for CSS issues, I really need to know what is your Base Theme and full ExtJS version... 4.2.0? 4.2.1? These things really change from theme to theme and each version.

Answer (score 1):

Im taking a guess here and going for ExtJS 4.2.1 with Classic theme.

So just change your CSS to

```
.invalid-component {
    background : #f4f777 !important;
    border: 2px dotted #ffee27; //works!!
}
```